# Using NEWUID() function in HANA database

Tags: sql, hana

I'm trying to use NEWUID() function to generate unique digits, but can't execute code because of probable errors in syntax.

How can I correct this one?

Thanks.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GENERATINGN (
    IN 
    p_docentryt NVARCHAR(50)
)
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT 
AS
BEGIN

 SELECT cast("ItemCode" || '-' || NEWUID() as nvarchar(50)) AS "UNIQUEIDENTIFIER"
 FROM "OITM"  
 WHERE "T0"."DocEntry" =  p_docentryt;
END;
```

It should be generate digits like this:

IT1225-513613161514161

Answer (score 0):

The code looks ok to me. Wat error message do you have? Can you tell a bit more about the HANA version you are using?

I executed the following similar SQL code and it worked:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GENERATINGN (IN p_docentryt NVARCHAR(50))
LANGUAGE SQLSCRIPT 
AS
BEGIN
SELECT cast("ItemCode" || '-' || NEWUID() as nvarchar(50)) AS "UNIQUEIDENTIFIER"
FROM (
  SELECT 'my-ItemCode' as "ItemCode" FROM DUMMY
);
END;
```